# How can I change the location of C++ output files in VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to change the default output file location in VS Code when I am coding in C++ and using MinGW debugger. When I debug the program, it will create the output file in the main folder. But can this output file be created in the subfolder (The P01 folder in the picture)?

Comment: most likely somewere in the settings for your c++ extension

Comment: use the `-o` option of the compiler

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Yes, you can.

Open the contents of your `.vscode/tasks.json` file. Just focus on the `args`:

```json
"args": [
    "-g",
    "${file}",
    "-o",
    "${fileDirname}/a.out",
],
```

When you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> (by default setting in VS Code) to start the debugging mode, `tasks.json` is executed to compile the program. Here, you can change the value of the 4th line with your desired location.

Note that the mentioned line content (of `tasks.json`) must be equivalent to the content of `"program"` of `.vscode/launch.json`. Otherwise, the program will be compiled successfully, but it won't be launched because the location will be mismatched.

Comment: This also works for other builds, I'm using C#.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how exactly you're performing builds.

#### For Build Tasks

If you're using a build [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), then you need to change the `args` property and add an argument to specify the output location for your compiler. Ex. For `gcc`, `-o <path>`. If you're just using one of the generated build tasks, then you'll need to write your own under `<workspace-folder-path>/.vscode/tasks.json`. You can find an example of a build task like this in [my answer](/a/77652228/11107541) to [What's the difference between the "Debug C/C++ File", "Run Code", and "Run C/C++ code" buttons in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77652090/11107541). Note that you can use [variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) to refer to paths like `${workspaceFolder}`, `${file}`, etc.

#### For CMake

If you're using [CMake Tools](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools) without [CMake Presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) (Ex. using [CMake Kits](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/kits.md)), then use the `cmake.buildDirectory` [setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings), which defaults to `"${workspaceFolder}/build"`.

For CMake Tools with CMake Presets, use the `binaryDir` property of your [configure preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset).

These control the path to the build directory. If you want to change where output files go *under* the build directory, see the various [target properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets) with `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` in their name, or the various corresponding [build variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#variables-that-control-the-build).

#### For Code Runner

If you're using the Code Runner extension (aside: I suggest that you don't- it's convenient for toy examples, but limited and flawed), then as with build tasks, you need to put a build flag for your compiler in [your `code-runner.executorMap` setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration)'s entry for `cpp`. See also in the linked docs the list of supported customized parameters, including `$workspaceRoot`, `$dir`, `$fileName`, `$fileNameWithoutExt`, etc. Ex.

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o \"$workspaceRoot/output/$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"$workspaceRoot/output/$fileNameWithoutExt\""
},
```