# What's the difference between the "Debug C/C++ File", "Run Code", and "Run C/C++ code" buttons in visual studio code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup Visual Studio Code to be able to compile and run C++ files. I got it all working but I have 5 different options to "run" the file, only 1 of which produces output to the terminal.

Image of the 3 buttons/options:
[image: Image of the 3 buttons/options]

The "Debug C/C++ File" and "Run C/C++ code" buttons seem to be doing identical things. There's also these 2 other buttons that seem to be doing the same thing.

Other 2 buttons:
[image: Other 2 button]

The "Run Code" button, shown in the first image, is the only one that produces output in the terminal. What's the difference between these 5 different buttons and why does only 1 produce an output?

I've already enabled "run code in integrated terminal" in the VSC settings, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: wow. asked on the same day as https://stackoverflow.com/q/77646301/11107541.

Comment: Consult at the helps of the installed extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### "Run Code <kbd>ctrl+alt+N</kbd>" comes from [`formulahendry.code-runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)

It builds the program in currently active file / editor tab and then runs it without / not under a debugger. You can configure what it does using [the `code-runner.executorMap` configuration setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration).

Commentary / warning: This extension is poorly implemented (shell escaping and quoting, compiler selection, etc.), and not needed when you have [the cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools).

---

#### "Run C/C++ File" and "Debug C/C++ File" come from [the cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools)

The C/C++ extension (cpptools) is contributing the other two options. The one with "Debug" in its name runs the current file under/with a debugger. The other one runs it without / not under a debugger. They have the same effect if you run `C/C++: Run C/C++ File`/`C/C++: Debug C/C++ File` in the command palette.

#### If you didn't configure a build task or launch config

Clicking the run/debug button will prompt you to "Select a debug configuration", at which point it will provide a list of builtin/detected launch configurations which can be used for basic debugging purposes like this:

> C/C++: <compiler> build and debug active file (preLaunchTask: C/C++ <compiler> build active file)
> Detected Task: (compiler: <compiler path>)

Take your pick of which compiler you want to use. The program will be run (with a debugger if you chose to run with debugging), and two [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics) instances will be created/used- one for the build task (that "preLaunchTask" thing) named something like "<compiler> build active file", and another for running your program named something like "cppdbg: <executable name>".

#### If you configure *one matching default* build task and don't have a launch config

Ex. under tasks.json in the `tasks` array property:

```json
{
   // https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference
   "type": "cppbuild",
   "label": "starball's g++ compile-active-file task",
   "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
   "args": [
      "-Wall", "-Wextra", // warnings
      "-g", // build with debug info
      "-fdiagnostics-color=always", // colour! :D
      "${file}", // source file to compile
      "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasename}" // output file. see also fileBasenameNoExtension
      // https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference
   ],
   "options": {
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}" // not really necessary
   },
   "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
   "group": {
      "kind": "build",
      "isDefault": "**/*.{cpp,cxx}" // adjust globbing as needed
   },
   "detail": "output file goes under ./build/"
},
```

Then the run button and corresponding commands will just use that build task and a generic launch config that fits it. You very very probably want the build task to not hardcode for specific file names unless you want the run button or the corresponding commands to only ever run/debug one specific file regardless of what file is currently focused/active.

If *multiple* tasks are registered to the build group and match for the current file, then you will be prompted to pick one (as opposed to cpptools assuming arbitrarily which one you want to use).

#### If you use a launch configuration

Pretty much the same answer as the above. If you have a default build task, the first launch configuration with that task as its `preLaunchTask` is used. If there is no default build task, or the default build task is defined in [the user-level tasks.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41046494/11107541), you'll be prompted which launch config to use.