# How to use different compilers for C and C++ in VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, settings

How can I use different compilers for C (gcc) and C++ (g++) in VS Code for Windows?

I don't understand how different settings work in VS Code, but I just want VS Code to automatically choose gcc for C and g++ for C++. I can use CodeRunner as a workaround, but then, when I'm trying to debug C++ code it shows me an error because the prebuild task is compile via gcc, which is not fully compatible with C++.

Comment: You can edit your tasks.json in each workspace folder you have to have independent compilers for each workspace.

Comment: ***I can use CodeRunner as a workaround*** I don't recommend using code-runner with c or c++ projects. It doesn't do anything more than the default and gets in your way once you have more than 1 source file or need to link any library other than the default.

Comment: @drescherjm So I need something like 2 different folders (workspaces) with different settings for each language?

Comment: Yes that was my idea.

Comment: @drescherjm So, that means I can't run more than 1 executable language per workspace?

Comment: You could use a Makefile and the [Makefile tools extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) if this is a requirement.

Comment: the cmake extension allows you to choose which project to build/run/debug, and you can have as many targets as you want.

Comment: Just call the compiler you wanna use?

Comment: make a launch config and compile task for C and C++, choose the right launch config based on the file you have, or use the Extension **Launch Configs** by ArturoDent

Answer (score 0):

This should just work if you get rid of Code Runner and just use the Microsoft C/C++ extension. Use the default/detected build tasks and launch configs, or define your own- one (or more) for C code and one (or more) for C++ code and appropriately set the `isDefault` build task property (Ex. `"isDefault": "**/*.{cpp,cxx}"` for C++ source files), and then optionally define corresponding launch configs or use detected ones with your default build tasks, which should all be recognized when using the "Run C/C++ Code" and/or "Debug C/C++ Code" commands/buttons (see [What's the difference between the "Debug C/C++ File", "Run Code", and "Run C/C++ code" buttons in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77652090/11107541) for related info).

If you're doing anything more complicated than a toy project or quick one-off C or C++ program, I'd highly recommend learning CMake and using the CMake Tools extension. There's definitely a learning curve, but it pays dividends in the cross-platform benefits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I'm just learning programming, I don't know if it's worth learning CMake initially.