# VS Code multiple C++ debug/compile buttons? (some in action bar, some in status bar)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've used VS Code for Arduino and not had any issues.  But now I'm trying to start a C++ project of my own, and the setup is a little weird for me.
**My environment:**
VS Code running on Win10
configured to remote debug on a headless raspberry pi

In the attached image of the IDE, I've circled the three buttons for this question.

1. Compile, but doesn't include the linker commands and so fails to link.
2. Same as 1, but then launches the debugger and complains that the file is out of date
3. Compiles, links and launches the debugger and runs the code

In Arduino I used buttons 1 & 2, so I'm not sure why it's different now.
[image]

Here is my task.json, I added the three linker commands for pigpio.

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-lpigpio",
            "-lrt",
            "-lpthread",
            ""
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

When I click **button1** to compile, this is the command executed(no linker commands):

```
Executing task: /bin/bash -c g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align 
-Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0 -c
/home/aaronl/lawnmower/src/lawnmower.cpp -o ./build/Debug/lawnmower.o && 
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wnull-dereference -g3 -O0   ./build/Debug/lawnmower.o -o ./build/Debug/outDebug
```

When I click **button3** this is the command executed(has linker commands):

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/aaronl/lawnmower/src/lawnmower.cpp -o 
/home/aaronl/lawnmower/src/lawnmower -lpigpio -lrt -lpthread
```

What am I missing?  Why doesn't button one use the task.json file?  Is there a different json file I should be editing?

**Requested list:**

```
C:\Users\aaron>code --list-extensions  
franneck94.c-cpp-runner  
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh  
ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit  
ms-vscode.cpptools  
ms-vscode.remote-explorer  
platformio.platformio-ide  
vadimcn.vscode-lldb
```

Comment: please add the output of running `code --list-extensions` in a terminal. if you have cmake tools installed, the stuff on the bottom is probably from cmake tools and I can write up an answer post. otherwise I don't know what the stuff on the bottom is from, but you can do an extension bisect to find out.

Comment: yep. the answer to your last question is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652228/11107541.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons in your status bar are coming from [`franneck94.c-cpp-runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=franneck94.c-cpp-runner). I assume for config and debug respectively. As for the button at the top right, that's coming from the cpptools extension. You can give it a specific behaviour by defining a default build task, which you can find an example of in my post [here](/a/77652228/11107541).

In general, if you want to find out which extension is contributing a specific behaviour, you can do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect). One other extension that I know contributes some similar stuff to the status bar (or *used to*) is the CMake Tools extension (though I think recently they've moved a lot of their status bar stuff to a dedicated view container).