# A classic mistake:does not exist launch: program '<filename>，sorry i cant solve the mistake

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

When I was learning C function calls my VScode again gave me this "error" prompt, the strange thing is that the other files above this folder can be debugged normally.
[image]

Next, it's my <kbd>launch.json</kbd> and <kbd>tasks.json</kbd> describe.

[launch.json](/questions/tagged/launch.json)

```
{
    // 使用 IntelliSense 了解相关属性。 
    // 悬停以查看现有属性的描述。
    // 欲了解更多信息，请访问: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) 启动",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "输入程序名称，例如 ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "将反汇编风格设置为 Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "(Windows) 启动",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            // "program": "输入程序名称，例如 ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myfile.exe",

            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) 启动",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "输入程序名称，例如 ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            // "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "E:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
            
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "将反汇编风格设置为 Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

[tasks.json](/questions/tagged/tasks.json)

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe 生成活动文件",
            "command": "E:\\WINGW\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

1.I have checked the configuration of my environment variables and it is fine

2.I have also tried to modify some of these configurations, but to no avail

thanks for your help:),I don't know if it is because of the Chinese characters in it, after all, my other files can be debugged normally:(
(The VScode is good but i was too weak)
(I'm not sure if my expression is clear, my English is not very good, if you didn't see some of the descriptions, I'm sorry)

Comment: Why does the error say `main.exe` but your launch.json file says program is `a.exe`?

Comment: how are you even launching? the run/debug view? the play button at the top right?  please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652228/11107541

Comment: I had try change a.exe to main.exe. But it`s still error.

Comment: i just play the button at the top right.Thanks ,i will view the post.