Any idea why tasks.json might be setup incorrectly by Visual Studio Code?
I am trying to setup Visual Studio Code to be able to just do the basics with C/C++ (run, debug, etc).  I created a new file (helloworld.cpp) and got the error "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exist code -1" and got a bunch of errors about undefined references such as:
C:/Users/LastName FirstName/Documents/Training/Test/helloworld/helloworld.cpp:9:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'

I can run the code just fine with "g++ -g -o helloworld helloworld.cpp".  Nothing complicated.  When I try and run it in Visual Studio Code, it's trying to use this:
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\LastName FirstName\Documents\Training\Test2\helloworld\helloworld.cpp" -o "C:\Users\LastName FirstName\Documents\Training\Test2\helloworld\helloworld.exe"

It looks like it's making things overly complicated and I have no idea what fdiagnostics is.
Below is the tasks.json file info it created for me:
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

I assume I have something wrong in VS Code.  Not sure if it's an extension issue, if something on my computer is setup incorrectly, etc.  I have minGCW installed (to the directory shown above) and added it to the path, g++ --version is providing a build version, I have the C/C++ extension installed for the latest version in VS Code.  At this point, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Any info you can give me would be appreciated.  Thanks!
*EDIT: My original folder had the above JSON file.  I created a new folder and placed the same .cpp file in it and tried to run it, got the same errors, but not .vscode folder (or tasks.json) file was created.  I have something configured wrong.  I assume it's gcc/g++ related?

Use g++ to compile C++ code and gcc to compile C code. You are currently using gcc according to cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe ...

terminated with exist code -1 - this is a result of the running task, the task itself must dump errors before exiting with the code -1. Be kind to post the errors.

I bet they have CodeRunner installed, and don't know that it's a dumpster fire of an extension that doesn't care about your tasks.json at all.

@RetiredNinja I deleted the .vscode folder in the root directory (turns out, it wasn't using the one in the folder, must have been left over) and used g++ and that seemed to work, though the newly created tasks.json file looks exactly the same (not sure what else got updated).  Regardless, it is now running g++ rather than gcc so it looks like that got fixed.  Thanks!

@sweenish no, this is the C/C++ (cpptools) extension. you can tell because the command has the new chcp wrapper that got added recently.

Good to know. I don't keep up with the extension's development, and it's rare that I bother with the tasks.json myself.

@RetiredNinja was correct.  It's trying to run a *.cpp file with gcc rather than g++.  I deleted the .vscode folder (which was in the project root directory, it's not using the folder in the actual file directory, might be leftover from earlier).  When I went to run it, I chose g++ and that seems to have resolved the issue.
Thanks everyone for your help!

this is quite strange. the one in your tasks.json should have been being used, since it was marked as the default build task. see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652228/11107541.
