Is there any way to configure VS code to work with SFML library directly with the "Run Code" button?
I've been trying to use the SFML library with Visual Studio Code and the C/C++ v1.19.9 Microsoft extension. My goal is to configure Visual Studio Code to compile and run SFML code directly from the editor using the "Run Code" button.
I'm starting with a simple code to open an empty window:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Window");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(); // Clear the window

        // Draw your graphics here

        window.display(); // Display what was drawn
    }

    return 0;
}

Initially, I compiled it via the terminal using the following command:
/usr/bin/g++ \
    -fdiagnostics-color=always \
    -g \
    main.cpp \
    -o main \
    -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/include \
    -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/lib \
    -lsfml-graphics \
    -lsfml-window \
    -lsfml-system \
    -lsfml-network


This worked fine, and the program compiled and ran successfully. However, I wanted to streamline the process by configuring my launch.json, tasks.json, and c_cpp_proppieties.json files to enable edit, compilation and execution directly within Visual Studio Code.
Here's what I did:
In c_cpp_proppieties.json, I added the path to the SFML include folder to help Visual Studio Code and the C/C++ extension understand the syntax:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Then in tasks.json, I defined a task to build the code with SFML:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file with SFML",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/include",
                "-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/lib",
                "-lsfml-graphics",
                "-lsfml-window",
                "-lsfml-system",
                "-lsfml-network"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}

and in the launch.json file, I updated the "preLaunchTask" to use the task defined in tasks.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        },
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file with SFML",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file with SFML"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

However, despite these configurations, I encountered the following error when trying to run the code:
[Running] cd "/Users/david/Desktop/c++ project/hello world sfml/" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "/Users/david/Desktop/c++ project/hello world sfml/"main

main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.052 seconds

I've been unable to find a solution so far. Does anyone have any insights into what might be missing? Thanks in advance for any help.

g++ main.cpp -o main  from the command line doesn't look much like what you asked for in tasks.json. Worth diging in and seeing why it's not being respected. Are you certain you saved the file after editing?

@user4581301, David, I suspect David is running using Code Runner instead of the C/C++ extension's run button. I suggest to read https://stackoverflow.com/q/77652090/11107541. also, note that you can scope default build tasks to specific languages, as is demonstrated in my answer to the linked question. if that explains your problem, I'll be inclined to close your question as a duplicate of it.

Use a build system. By the time you are incorporating third party libraries, you need to learn cmake/meson/etc. And preferably a package manager at the same time. And stop using Coderunner, if it is the case that you're using it.

As @sweenish suggestion, use a build system. I would suggest CMake. It will streamline your development and save you a lot of headache. Works great with VSCode too.

I attempted to use the solution provided by @starball, but I encountered an issue with the '.run' extension, which I preferred not to use. Consequently, I uninstalled it and opted for the 'button' included with the cpptools extension, as suggested in the previous answer. However, the problem persisted. In an effort to resolve it, I reinstalled the C/C++ v1.19.9 Microsoft extension and adjusted both the 'task.json' and 'launch.json' files. Here's what my tasks look like now:
{
"tasks": [
    // Task for building C/C++ code with SFML
    {
        "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file with SFML", // Name of the task
        "type": "shell", // Specifies the type of task as a shell command
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++", // Command to execute
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always", // Enable colored diagnostics
            "${file}", // Placeholder for the current active file
            "-o", // Output flag
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", // Output filename based on directory and base filename
            "-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/include", // Include SFML headers
            "-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/sfml/2.6.1/lib", // Specify SFML library directory
            "-lsfml-graphics", // Link SFML graphics library
            "-lsfml-window", // Link SFML window library
            "-lsfml-system", // Link SFML system library
            "-lsfml-network" // Link SFML network library
        ],
        "group": "build", // Task group (build)
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent", // Do not show the output when this task is executed
            "echo": false, // Do not echo the executed command in the terminal
            "focus": false, // Do not bring focus to the terminal when this task is executed
            "panel": "shared" // Show the output in a shared terminal panel
        }
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0" // Version of the tasks configuration

}
And the updated launch configuration:
{
"configurations": [
    // Configuration for building and running C/C++ code with SFML
    {
        "name": "C/C++: Build and Run", // Name of the configuration
        "type": "cppdbg", // Type of debugger (C/C++ debugger)
        "request": "launch", // Specifies that this configuration launches the debugger
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}", // Path to the executable to debug
        "args": [], // Arguments to pass to the executable
        "stopAtEntry": false, // Whether to stop at the entry point of the program
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}", // Current working directory for the debugger
        "environment": [], // Environment variables to set for the debugger
        "externalConsole": false, // Whether to use an external console for input/output
        "MIMode": "lldb", // Debugger mode (LLDB in this case)
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file with SFML" // Task to run before launching the debugger
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0" // Version of the configurations

}
Besides configuring to eliminate the debugging process, I remove any other tasks that I don't really need.
To @sweenish and @André Lehto, I will try CMake in the future. Thanks for your recommendation.
